# knockout not working in MVC4 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have the following in my Index.cshtml file (from the knockout site):

```
<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
<h2>Hello, <span data-bind="text: fullName"> </span>!</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Here's my data model
    var ViewModel = function (first, last) {
        this.firstName = ko.observable(first);
        this.lastName = ko.observable(last);

        this.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
            // Knockout tracks dependencies automatically. It knows that fullName depends on firstName and lastName, because these get called when evaluating fullName.
            return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
        }, this);
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth")); // This makes Knockout get to work
</script>
```

My Layout has this line:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
```

Which is configured correctly in bundler config:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/knockout").Include(
                "~/Scripts/Libraries/knockout-2.2.1.js"));
```

Chrome sees the file and VS is giving me intellisense, so I'm not sure what's going on.  None of the knockout functions are working.

I tested this outside of MVC (just using html/css) and it worked fine.  Any idea what's going on?

EDIT: I tried using a direct reference without bundler and it still doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Libraries/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>
```

I'm getting an error from chrome:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ko is not defined
```

Comment: Can you post your `~/bundles/bootstrap` bundle configuration? You can try to put your script inside the `@section scripts { }`

Comment: thanks - yes one moment

Comment: Sorry, copied the wrong line.  It's knockout in my page.

Comment: Have you tried to put your `<script>` inside the scripts section `@section scripts { }`? Are there any errors in your browser JS console?

Comment: Yes, I did put it in scripts{} to no avail.  Chrome is giving me "Uncaught ReferenceError: ko is not defined" in its console...

Comment: Sounds like your viewmodel script is running before KnockoutJS has loaded.

Comment: in chrome development enviroment (F12) could you see, in the tab network, the script `knockout-2.2.1.js` loading without errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you post some JS console error from chrome or firebug? Looks like a missing reference from knockout.

EDIT: Put your script at the end of its view! Another thing, the reference for knockout must stay below the reference for jquery, because its dependent.

EDIT:
Register the knockout

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/knockout").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/knockout-{version}.js"));
```

Render It in your view

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
```

Answer (score 0):

Include your javascript code in a JS file and render this after knockout

Like this:

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/MYSCRIPTS")
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by removing my script line at the end of my Index.cshtml file:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/ConfigGroup.js"></script>
```

and replacing it with:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/ConfigGroup.js")
}
```

I guess section Scripts gets loaded at a different time than  includes.